# Issue using regular expression matching in BigQuery

Tags: sql, regex, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am attemping to perform a regular expression search in BigQuery using text from the GOV.UK web page relating to guidance on [living in italy](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/living-in-italy).

The text from the page can be seen in raw form [here](https://pastebin.com/UFeqc2Yv).

Specifically, I am attempting to match the phrase '*UK driving licence*'. This phrase appears once in the text (on line 355).

I am able to detect a match using the [`CONTAINS_SUBSTR`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#contains_substr) function; however, I am **not** able to match this phrase using regular expressions.

The following statement returns `FALSE`:

`REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(UK driving licence)')`

I have observed that:

- Using the combination of [`ARRAY_LENGTH`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_length) and [`REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) functions, I can match the word '*UK*' the correct number of times (71) in the text;
- [`REGEXP_CONTAINS`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains) can match '*extend recognition of valid*' (the phrase immediately preceding '*UK driving licence*'), returning `TRUE`;
- `REGEXP_CONTAINS` can match '*driving licences in italy*' (the phase immediately following/overlapping '*UK driving licence*'), returning `TRUE`,
- The issue does not appear to relate to case sensitivity, because I've tried various combinations of using [`LOWER`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#lower) and manually matching using lower-case search values

I am completely stumped as to why I cannot use regex to match for this pattern - is this a bug?

Comment: what resulrt you get from `REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'UK driving')`

Answer (score 1):

This was occuring because of invisible unicode characters in the text.

I was able to use the [`NORMALIZE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#normalize) function (as described on this [Towards Data Science article](https://towardsdatascience.com/bigquery-functions-for-data-cleaning-4b96181fbc3)) to mitigate the presence of invisible characters in the text I was searching.

In particular, I used the NFKC (Normalization Form Compatibility Composition) option.